# Apply discount to specific product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new at PHP and woocommerce. I am trying to apply a discount % to a product category. By searching I have found the following code that seems to work for me but I can't display the price in the product loop. There is a bubble showing with 30% off but the sale price is the same as the regular price.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'custom_sale_price_for_category', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price', 'custom_sale_price_for_category', 10, 2 );


function custom_sale_price_for_category( $sale_price, $product ) {

//Get all product categories for the current product
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $categories[] = $term->slug;
}

if ( ! empty( $categories ) && in_array( 'pinakes', $categories, true ) ) {
    
        $price = $product->get_regular_price() * 0.7;
    
}

return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `woocommerce_product_get_sale_price` filter has been deprecated since WooCommerce 3.0. You can change the price display and the price in your cart by using the `woocommerce_get_price_html` filter and the `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` filter.

In this case I've added a helper function called `check_discount_categories` that will let you set the discounted categories and the discount percentage.

Please note that these filters apply the discount to the regular price of your product to make sure the custom discount is not applied on top of an existing sale price. So if your product already has a sale price these filters basically set a new sale price.

Also note this is a frontend solution. So right now this won't work when creating an order through the backend.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_display_on_specific_categories', 9999, 2 );
function custom_price_display_on_specific_categories( $price_html, $product ) {

    if ( is_admin() || empty( $product->get_price() ) ) return $price_html;
    
    $product_id = $product->get_parent_id() ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();
    $discount = check_discount_categories( $product_id );

    if ( $discount['apply'] ) {
        if ( $product->get_type()  == 'variable' ) {
            $price_html = sprintf( '%s - %s', wc_price( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min' ) * $discount['percentage'] ), wc_price( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max' ) * $discount['percentage'] ) );
        } else {
            $price_html = wc_price( $product->get_regular_price() * $discount['percentage'] );
        }
    }
    
    return $price_html;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_price_cart_on_specific_categories', 9999 );
function custom_price_cart_on_specific_categories( $cart ) {
 
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) return;
 
    // Apply discount to cart
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_id = $product->get_parent_id() ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();
        $discount = check_discount_categories( $product_id );
        if ( $discount['apply'] ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $product->get_regular_price() * $discount['percentage'] );
        }
    }
}

function check_discount_categories( $product_id ) {
    $discount['apply'] = false;
    $discount['percentage'] = 0.7;
    $discount['categories'] = array( 'pinakes', 'posters', 'music' );
    
    // Get all product categories for the current product
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $product_categories[] = $term->slug;
    }

    // Check for discounted categories
    if ( !empty( $product_categories ) ) {
        // Get array of category matches
        $cat_matches = array_intersect( $discount['categories'], $product_categories );
        if ( count( $cat_matches ) > 0 ) {
            // 1 or more matches
            $discount['apply'] = true;
        }
    }
    return $discount;
}
```

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but I would like to show both regular and sale price at my shop. With this solution it seems like it modifies the regular price.

Comment: Thanks for this @Barba, it's kind of frustrating when we polish an answer, OP just has to make adjustments to fit their needs but they are "I need something extra" :/

Comment: I'm getting double a double pricing https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/25175503?key=0469b184e610c534a1bd02424b035ce4 do you offer code customization?

Comment: @HuseinYuseinov you can shoot me an email. Check [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13806652/terminator-barbapapa?tab=profile) for more details.